# Can we skip in Java8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, skip

I have a for loop which iterates across the employeeId list. In each iteration it calls a service to see if it has any values, if we get any values for an id then we need to skip all the remaining iteration. I have done that by using traditional for loop like as shopn below

```
for(int i=0; i<employeeIdLists.length; i++) {
    userDetails = someService.getUserId(employeeIdLists.get(i));
    if(userDetails != null) {
        i = employeeIdLists.length; // skip rest of the iteration
    }
}
```

I would like to know if I can do the similar one using Java Streams. I tried some but this is not meeting the expectations

```
employeeIdLists.stream()
.map(id -> someService.getUserId(id))
.filter(userDetails -> userDetails!=null)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: since you are actually looking for the first occurrence or any such occurrence you shall be aware of `findAny` and `findFirst`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do that with `findAny()` or `findFirst()`, which would stop the pipeline the first time a value is found (after the filter, in your case):

```
userDetails = employeeIdLists.streams()
    .map(id -> someService.getUserId(id))
    .filter(userDetails -> userDetails!=null)
    .findAny()
    .orElse(null); //null if all values were null
```

In this pipeline, `userDetails` will be set to a value  that did not get a null result from the service, and the pipeline will be stopped as soon as such value is found.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which one suits for my case `findAny()` or `findFirst()`

Comment: If you want to deterministically get the first element that got a non-null result, then use `findFirst()`. Otherwise `findAny()` should be fine.